# Как установить только SQL*Plus на Windows?

Tags: oracle, windows, sql

Есть машина с Windows XP. Насколько знаю, можно установить консоль SQL*Plus без SQL Developer, и вообще без Oracle на машине.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Installing SQL*Plus Instant Client from the UNIX or Windows Zip Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ape.htm)

На странице по ссылке есть ряд инструкций. Все сводится к тому, чтобы с сайта Oracle скачать два архива для Instant Client на Microsoft Windows (32-bit): один архив для Instant Client, другой - для SQL Plus. Список нужных файлов - по первой ссылке. Архивы надо распаковать, взять из них нужные файлы и положить в одну папку. После этого exe-файл sqlplus.exe будет запускать консоль.

Answer (score 3):

В последних версиях Oracle пытается уговорить пользователей перейти с SQL*Plus на его последователя - SQLcl. Это "облегчённая" версия SQL Developer без GUI, то есть только командная строка. Oracle обещает полную совместимость с SQL*Plus.

Взять SQLcl можно:

- прямо с установленной БД по пути: `$ORACLE_HOME/sqldeveloper/`
- либо скачать с [официального сайта](https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html)

Поместить в какой-либо каталог на Windows машине, добавить этот каталог в `PATH`.

Вроде всё:

```
C:\> set path=D:\app\oracle\sqlcl\bin;%path%
C:\> sql user/pass@dbserver.domain.net:1521/pdb1

SQLcl: Release 19.4 Production on Thu Jul 22 18:29:03 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Do Jul 22 2021 18:29:05 +03:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Comment: полностью поддерживаю! одна только полноценная история команд стоит того, чтобы перейти на `SQLcl`, не говоря уже про остальные нововведения ;)

Comment: а смысл? тогда уж sql plus использовать, а SQL Developer вполне неплох и так и история запросов там нормально работает.

Comment: @NMD Не совсем понятен ваш комментериий. Смысл чего?

Comment: @0xdb, в чем смысл установки консольной версии sql developer, если есть sql plus?

Comment: @NMD На обычной машине нет никакого sqlplus. Если он нужен, то можно или  его установить, или установить SQLcl, который с ним совместим и даст парочку новых фичь.

Comment: @0xdb, ох, точно, с такой точки зрения не рассматривал.